# How to run SSIS packages dynamically?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

We have a large production MSSQL database (mdf appx. 400gb) and i have a test database. All the tables,indexes,views etc. are same eachother. I need to make sure that tha datas in the tables of this two database consistent. so i need to insert all the new rows and update all the updated rows into test db from production every night.

I came up with idea of using SSIS packages to make the data consistent by checking updated rows and new rows in all the tables. My SSIS Flow is ;

I have packages in SSIS for each tables seperately because;
Orderly;

1. Im getting the timestamp value in the table in order to get last 1 day rows instead of getting whole table.
2. I get the rows of the table in the production
3. Then im using 'Lookup' tool to compare this data with the test database table data.
4. Then im using conditional sprit to get a clue whether the data is new or updated.
5. If the data is new, i insert this data to the destination
   5_2. If the data is updated, then i update the data in the destination table.

[image]

Data flow is in the MTRule and STBranch package in the picture

The problem is, im repeating creating all this single flow for each table and i have more than 300 table like this. It takes hours and hours :(

What im asking is;

Is there any way in SSIS to do this dynamically ?

PS: Every single table has its own columns and PK values but my data flow schema is always same. . (Below)

[image]

Comment: Why not nightly backup restore work for test db? If it is for testing purpose we cannot overload production data. Do you have any scrubbing requirement in test?

Comment: I forgot to say that i cannot perform any backup-restore operations since our prod sql is on cloud but the test sql is not. And also for some other reasons, cant move the backup file from cloud to test server..

Comment: What is the amount of data? Do you have delta attribute set for all the major tables? If you are going to do full load for all the tables with large volume, then that is also going to be costly operation

Comment: Yes, thats why i have to use conditional sprit and Timest values to get just new inserted and updated data in the last day. Not the whole table. I know its gonna be a costly operation, so i will schedule it to run at nights once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222388/ssis-best-practice-to-load-n-tables-from-source-to-target-server/20226661#20226661

Comment: @billinkc thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into BiMLScript, which lets you create packages dynamically based on metadata.

Comment: yes, it seems right and most logical,easy way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to achieve this is to use Expressions. They empower you to dynamically set the source and Destination.
One possible solution might be as follows:

- create a table which stores all your table names and PK columns
- define a package which Loops through this table and which parses a SQL Statement
- Call your main package and pass the stmt to it
- Use the stmt as Data Source for your Data Flow
- if applicable, pass the Destination Table as Parameter as well (another column in your config table)

This is how I processed several really huge tables: the data had to be fetched from 20 tables and moved to one single table.

Comment: I will try that for sure. Im gonna tell you the results. thanks

Comment: Since I just had to work on one of These packages, here a further hint: in the Source you don't Need an Expression but the "SQL Command from Variable" - there you will have to put the Parameter with the stmt.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off writing a stored procedure that takes the tablename as parameter and doing your CRUD there.

Then call the stored procedure in a `FOR EACH` component in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use SSIS?

You are better off writing a stored procedure that takes the tablename as parameter and doing your CRUD there. Then call the stored procedure in a `FOR EACH` component in SSIS.

In fact you might be able to do everything using a Stored Procedure and scheduling it in a SQL Agent Job.