# Need to embed a "Data Flow" inside a "For Each Loop" in SSIS

Tags: for-loop, ssis

I want to transfer data from an Azure PowerApps (SQL) database to an On-Premise SQL Database.

There are around 10 Million rows in the database spread between about 30 tables.  There are about six tables with circa 1 million rows with the rest all having far less.

I created an SSIS script which downloads the data from each table 5000 rows at a time using a data flow task.  The problem is there are frequent changes to the structure of the source database and each time it changes I effectively need to download the whole database again.

I also need to change lots of parts in the source code too as it is essentially a chunk of code which has to be copied for each table and adjusted accordingly after changes.

Is there a way I could use a data flow task within a for-each loop to programmatically update the information for the different tables?

I am thinking this would be easier as I could have a couple of tables called 'tabname' and 'tabfields' which I could pass into the data flow task.

I want to use a for each loop to execute a data transfer from a PowerApps database to a local database

The basic flow for my current process is shown in the image below but I would love to use a single container if possible to simplify it.

[image: Current Process Flow]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So what happens when the data structure changes? I *assume* you'd need to reset your high water mark back to zero

Comment: Correct billnkc.  Reload the entire package.  This is done by updating all of the stages on the tables which have changed and then rerunning the script with the 'Number of Days (NoDays)' variable set to a value larger than the service has been in operation for.  Hence my desire for something easier to manage.

Comment: You're looking for a replication solution from a PowerApps DB (Is it Dataverse or is it SQL PaaS?) SSIS does not deal with schema changes at all. More modern tools like ADF handles this a bit better. You may want to consider that going from PowerApps, back to on prem via SSIS is a technological step backwards.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, this is a chipshot [Biml](http://www.varigence.com/bimlexpress) [pattern](http://bimlscript.com).

The worker pattern looked like

[image]

I had a table, ETL.RunLoad

- Surrogate key
- QualifiedTableName
- SourceRowCount
- Insert/Update/DeleteCount
- InsertDate
- UpdateDate
- LastSyncedDate
- LastSyncedNumber

This table was my run log, when a package kicks off, it records the start time, preserving the Surrogate key for easy update.

It then looks up the last successful run (I only populate UpdateDate when complete). The systems I was dealing with either has an integer or a date field that I needed to use for high water mark.

I'd truncate the raw schema version of my table as that was a scratchpad.

A data flow task which was as simple as I could make it: Source to Row Count to Destination. I don't need to worry about insert vs update at this point because  I just wanted the data in "my" environment as quickly as possible.

[image]

Even though the next task is labeled Merge, I implement it as an update followed by an insert (capturing the row counts and kicking it back to Variables).

The final task is updating the run log with the counts, the completion time and the new highwater mark (very important).

I then had a low rent orchestrator as the client refused to give any requirements around how they wanted it to work until everything was delivered and then they had ideas of how I should have done things.

The tables always existed in pairs so "base" tables and the "reoccurs" so I enumerated through the list of entities in parallel. Lots of clever ways to parallelize this but this at least had two streams running parallel.

[image]

A person could build all these by hand, it's not the worst and from 2005 to 2010/2011, that's how I did it until I started digging into automation. Using the native SSIS libraries, to EzAPI and finally Biml. Hands down, Biml is the winner for using pattern based development. The folks at Varigence are crazy smart.

Biml needs two things to work: metadata and your patterns. If you're just selecting data from tables based on a time-key column, you can point Biml at the database and have it retrieve the metadata for the tables. Your patterns are the cookie cutters for the metadata dough.

This project was 3 "real" files. My "Driver" file enumerated through the metadata and created a package via a *function call*, if you will, to the "inc_Package"

Once all the packages were created in the driver, I knew all the resulting package names and used to create the Orchestrator package "inc_Orchestrator" as well as the Project file.

[image]

A crude version of this can be found on my [Biml Replicate-o-Matic](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/01/biml-replicate-o-matic.html) post which was driven by [ssis best practice to load N tables from Source to Target Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222388/ssis-best-practice-to-load-n-tables-from-source-to-target-server/20226661#20226661) The caveats in that post are out of date as ugh, that was 10 years ago and the process is much cleaner now.

### Why I like it

Besides that I wrote it, this approach allows you to focus on the business problem: we need to keep these tables in sync for Reasons.

"Hey Bill, the packages failed."

Yup, the error says metadata changed. Hang tight.

I then clicked the 10 package (which got the current metadata definition). I clicked on 20 to build all the artifacts and then the 100 script deployed the ispac and scripts to the azure instance.

I was out of the business of trying to figure out what changed and was in the business of clicking buttons ;)